# filter price range using filtering_params["price"]

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So far I've set up filtering all products by price range, but I have sale prices on items as well, and I need the sale prices on sales items to be included in the accurate filtering range.

For example, an item priced at $50 has a sale price of $30, I need this item to show up when I filter the range $30-$40, but it's only showing up when filtering $40-$50.

Where and how do I include the "sale_price"? (still new and learning RoR)

In my **listings_controller.rb** file I have:

```
@listings = Listing.filter(params.slice(:category, :price))
```

And I have a **models > concerns > filterable.rb** file that has:

```
module Filterable
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    module ClassMethods
        def filter filtering_params

            return self.all if filtering_params.empty?

            if filtering_params["category"]
            results = self.includes(:category).where(categories: { name: filtering_params["category"] })

          elsif filtering_params["price"]
              min = filtering_params["price"].split('-').first
              max = filtering_params["price"].split('-').last
              results = self.where("price >= :min AND price <= :max", min: min, max: max)

          end
          results
        end
    end
end
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can do this.

Here's one:

```
results = self.where("MIN(price, sale_price) >= :min AND MIN(price, sale_price) <= :max", min: min, max: max)
```

This assumes that `sale_price` is always set. If it isn't you can do something like this:

```
results = self.where("(price >= :min AND price <= :max) OR (sale_price IS NOT NULL AND sale_price >= :min AND sale_price <= :max)", min: min, max: max)
```

Comment: seems logical, however, I'm getting this error: "PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function min(numeric, numeric) does not exist"

Comment: and when I changed the min = to "min = filtering_params["price, sale_price"].split('-').first", I now get an error saying: "undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass". should I keep the sale_price out of the "min = ..." ? I need to define it somewhere correct?

Comment: thanks for the quick replies Finbarr, I tried your second option and it filters, but still not filtering on the sales_price.

Comment: hi Finbarr, we're halfway there, the sale_price is filtering properly, however, the sale item is also showing up as the reg. price as well. any last ideas?